# Force close stating Unable to start activity component info

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-sqlite

I am calling an activity from another activity via intents and passing values through bundle(String values) but It could not start the activity this is the code and log cat errors please help me solve this

### Activity which is calling another activity

```
if(v==btndate){
    Intent i2=new Intent(accounts.this,calcok.class);
        String frm=edtdate1.getText().toString();
        String to=edtdate2.getText().toString();
        Log.e("acc->calcok","inbetween intents");
        Log.e("from date",frm);
            Log.e("to date",to);
        i2.putExtra("from",(String)frm);
        i2.putExtra("to",(String) to);
        startActivity(i2);
}
```

### Acitivity called by the previous one

```
package dlp.android.digichronicle;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class calcok extends Activity{
DBHandandler  myDbHelper=new DBHandandler(this);
SQLiteDatabase Mydatabase;
float inc,exp;
String s1,s2,s3;
String stattionlist,DBname="widgets";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.myDbHelper = new DBHandandler(this);
     Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
System.out.println("Got from acc"+b);
String frm=b.getString("frm");
String to=b.getString("to");
    if(b!=null)
    {

        Log.e("frm",frm);
        Log.e("to",to);
             Log.e("Entered accounts->" +"CALCCCC","");
             try {
                    FetchingData();
                    myDbHelper.openDataBase();

                    Mydatabase = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                    String s =second.ge;

                    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("accounts")){
                ArrayList<Float> inclist=new  ArrayList<Float>();
                ArrayList<Float> explist=new ArrayList<Float>();
                        try{
                 explist =myDbHelper.calc(Mydatabase,"exp",frm,to);

                inclist =myDbHelper.calc1(Mydatabase,frm,to);
                         }
                         catch(Exception e){
                        inclist.add(500.0f);
                                explist.add(320.0f);
                         }
                float inc= sum(inclist);
                float exp= sum(explist);
                    float sav=inc-exp;
                    if(sav<0){
                        s3="Deficit Amount";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            s3=Float.toString(sav);
                        }
                        s1=Float.toString(inc);
                        s2=Float.toString(exp);
                      }
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GOt Details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             } catch (SQLException e) {
                 //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        myDbHelper.close();
        Mydatabase.close();
        Intent i3=new Intent(calcok.this,accounts.class);
       i3.putExtra("inc",s1);
       i3.putExtra("exp",s2);
       i3.putExtra("sav",s3);
        startActivity(i3);
       }

         }
 public static float sum(ArrayList<Float> list){
      if(list==null || list.size()<1)
        return 0;

      float sum = 0;
      for(Float i: list)
        sum = sum+i;

      return sum;
    }

private void FetchingData() {


     try {  myDbHelper.onCreateDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    } 
    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        Mydatabase = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }

}
  }
```

### Logcat errors

```
11-24 20:52:26.318: I/System.out(842): cursortrue
11-24 20:52:29.267: D/Testing(842): Checkpoint 2
11-24 20:52:29.647: D/dalvikvm(842): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9093K, 24% free 30100K/39303K, paused 91ms
 11-24 20:52:29.817: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
 11-24 20:52:29.837: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 11-24 20:52:32.247: D/dalvikvm(842): GC_CONCURRENT freed 655K, 21% free 31399K/39303K, paused 5ms+23ms
 11-24 20:52:32.337: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
 11-24 20:52:32.366: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 11-24 20:52:32.767: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
 11-24 20:52:32.797: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 11-24 20:52:35.757: E/acc->calcok(842): inbetween intents
 11-24 20:52:35.847: I/System.out(842): Got from accBundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=64]
 11-24 20:52:35.847: D/AndroidRuntime(842): Shutting down VM
 11-24 20:52:35.858: W/dalvikvm(842): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{dlp.android.digichronicle/dlp.android.digichronicle.calcok}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
  11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at and roid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at dlp.android.digichronicle.calcok.onCreate(calcok.java:30)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at an droid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
  11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
  11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):    ... 11 more
   11-24 20:52:36.297: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
  11-24 20:52:36.317: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
  11-24 20:52:36.567: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
  11-24 20:52:36.576: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
  11-24 20:52:37.117: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
  11-24 20:52:37.137: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
  11-24 20:52:37.619: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
   11-24 20:52:37.647: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
   11-24 20:52:38.147: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
   11-24 20:52:38.177: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
   11-24 20:52:38.697: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
  11-24 20:52:38.707: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
  11-24 20:52:39.217: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
   11-24 20:52:39.237: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
   11-24 20:52:39.737: I/dalvikvm(842): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
  11-24 20:52:39.757: I/dalvikvm(842): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
  11-24 20:52:39.877: I/Process(842): Sending signal. PID: 842 SIG: 9
  11-24 20:52:41.037: I/dalvikvm(857): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
  11-24 20:52:41.107: I/dalvikvm(857): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
  11-24 20:52:41.246: D/dalvikvm(857): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 70K, 3% free 9121K/9347K, paused 68ms
```

Comment: i wonder to see there is no setcontentview() here. I am not sure whether i am unable to find it or if its absent

Comment: here i am just extracting the values from database and performing calculations on the data it does not require any setContentView() i guess.@G_S

Comment: well i dont think so. You are calling this activity from another activity using intents for which u need to show a way (an xml may be) for the activity

Comment: and even write String frm=b.getString("from");
String to=b.getString("to"); inside the if(b!=null)

Comment: and next check out @varevarao's solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `frm` is `null` in the `calcok` Activity (As it very clearly states in Logcat).

```
11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
 11-24 20:52:35.897: E/AndroidRuntime(842):     at dlp.android.digichronicle.calcok.onCreate(calcok.java:30)
```

So, I guess it's the way you're receiving the extras. Try:

```
String frm = getIntent().getStringExtra("frm");
String to = getIntent().getStringExtra("to");
```

**EDIT**: Just realized you're putting the extra as `from`, and receiving it as `frm`. That's the error.

Answer (score 0):

See this line in your logcat: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message. Somewhere you are not passing any print message to your log statement. Plz check all your log statement gain. And make sure you have included the activity in the AndroidManifest file.
And while recieving the intent You are missing out. Try recieving intents as suggested. It will surely get resolved.

Comment: Sir that is the code am using and there is no problem with any Log ant Print statements. and I also included activity in manifest file what might be the problem sir